# Get all windows from all threads

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I start in my application some threads like

```
  this.Thread = new Thread(() =>
  {
      System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
      {
         ...
         ...

      }));
      System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
                           }) { IsBackground = true, Name = Constants.SPECIAL_UI_THREAD_NAME};
  this.Thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
  this.Thread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
  this.Thread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
  this.Thread.Start();
```

They have all a Window which is generated and shown.
Now, when I use in my Main-Thread

> Application.Current.Windows

I don't get the windows of my additional threads.

How can I get all windows of all threads of my application?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be creating windows on any thread other than the application's main thread. Instead, have all windows created on the main app thread and use other threads (e.g. task parallel library) to do work asynchronously such that the main application's thread (and therefore UI) remains responsive.

Comment: I need creating windows on other threads because of the performance of window-creating. This is all working great. Now I have the problem to get the windows from the other threads.

Comment: @t.kehl The "performance of window-creating" is great and always good enough. Maybe it takes too much time to get the data. Then move that to a thread.

Comment: @Henk Holterman - But my question was not about creating windows in a thread - this is here working great and I can't change this - instead I am searching a way to get all windows which are created in different threads.

Comment: @t.kehl - You'll have to create a little administration yourself.