# Application.Current.Windows doesn't contain all created Window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, multithreading, xaml

I created (and shown) a Window as follows :

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
   {
        notificationPopUp = new NotificationPopUpView(unreadNotifications.First().session_s, unreadNotifications.First().secondry_msg);
        notificationPopUp.Show();
        Dispatcher.Run();

   });

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();
```

when I try to itterate through the created Windows using :

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
     windowsList = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>();
});

foreach (var window in windowsList)
{
     Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
     {
         if (window.DataContext == viewModel)
         {
              returnValue = window;
         }
     });
}
```

The `windowsList` seem to have only two Windows (the MainWindowView, and another one) but not the `NotificationPopUpView`, what would be the cause of this ? I don't know what I'm missing ? please explain to me what is the problem and how can I correct this ?

Comment: As a rough guess: the UI should be in the UI thread. Not in any other thread. You probably don't see your windows created in different threads.

Comment: Just look [at the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,1357fc2806388b54).  No, NonAppWindowsInternal is not accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what would be the cause of this ? I don't know what I'm missing ?
>   please explain to me what is the problem and how can I correct this ?

`Application.Current.Windows` only contains windows that exist on the main UI thread. Because you created `notificationPopUp` on a new thread, it's naturally missing there. It's not good practice to create windows on any other thread but the main UI thread. If there is a lot of data processing involved, you should separate that to a background thread instead of the window creation to keep the UI responsive.

Similiar question on StackOverflow: [Get all windows from all threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267143/get-all-windows-from-all-threads).